# Java with Groovy handling of closures throwing Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, groovy

We have a system that is possible to customise using groovy scripts and I've spotted a very strange effect on the type of exceptions throw from these scripts.

We have a groovy script with the following:

```
process {
   throw new Exception("weeee")
}
```

Process is defined as a Closure in the base class of the script:

```
public abstract class ScriptBaseClass extends Script {
   Closure process;

   public void process( Closure code ) {
      process = (Closure) code.clone();
   } 
}
```

In the **Java class** that actually runs the scripts we have the following method (omitted all the set up code as it doesn't seem relevant):

```
public void process() {
   try {
      script.process.call();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.debug("exception thrown from groovy script", e);
      throw e;
   }
}
```

Note the process method here doesn't declare it throws any exceptions. However it quite clearly re-throws the Exception e that it caught. This code is valid, it compiles and runs quite happily. It throws the Exception as I wanted.

Does any one know how this is legal code? In theory I shouldn't be able to throw a checked exception out of a method that doesn't declare that it throws it.

Comment: yes, it's legal in groovy. cannot find any mention in docs btw, but it was always working

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Indeed I know it is legal in groovy, however the process method above which re-throws the exception is in a Java class. Normally if you throw a checked exception you must declare it. This seems to be a odd case around the interface of the two languages.

Comment: oh, sorry, first part about groovy was confusing, so i've missed part about java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works because Java compiler (starting since Java 7) can determine re-thrown exception. For `catch (Exception e)` it thinks it's `RuntimeException` because there were no other (checked) exception declared in `call()`.

You can read about it there, for example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html

So this code compiles perfectly:

```
public void xxxxx() {
    try {
        System.out.println('Hi!'); //or anything else w/o declared exceptions
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Java compiled sees that only RuntimeException could be caught here, so it doesn't ask you do declare anything.

But for this:

```
public void xxxxx() {
    try {
        throw new IOException(); //or anything that have declared checked exception
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

it will fail to compile, because `IOException` could be caught and re-thrown

Comment: Great answer. Without other languages mixed into the JVM this is a reasonable (if a bit confusing) thing to do. However it does mean we need to be very careful when interfacing with groovy code.

Answer (score 2):

Introducing closures or anything Groovy related is unnecessary complexity.  The following is valid Java code:

```
public class Demo {
    public void someMethod() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the following is not valid and will not compile:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Demo {
    public void someMethod() {
        try {
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("", "", "");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Groovy and the JVM don't really care about an exception being a checked one or not. Only the Java compiler cares about this here. In fact you can use the catch on any RuntimeException or its parent classes (of which Exception is one) without requiring it being declared as thrown from something called in the try-block. So it is fine by the compiler to catch Exception or Throwable even. Of course, from a program logic view it is an entirely different matter.

Comment: I know groovy and the jvm don't care about checked vs unchecked exceptions however the process method is in a Java class, thus run through the Java Compiler which is why I'm confused how it is valid code.

Comment: "Only the Java compiler cares about this here" was thought as sentence to make clear I am talking about the Java compiler from here on now.